# MySQL Query for multiplication, addition and division

Tags: mysql

I am trying to formulate a query listed below;

```
Select SUM(IF (faultdistribution='crs', 1,0)*8 OR
    IF (faultdistribution='configuration', 1,0)* 6 OR
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 4 OR
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='major', 1,0)* 2 OR
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='moderate', 1,0)* 5 OR
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='minor', 1,0)* 3 OR
    IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 2 OR
    IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='major', 1,0)* 1) as mysum 
    FROM tbl_fault WHERE product='DAS' AND faultdistribution='missed'
```

What i intend to do is add all or any one or two IF conditions that are true. Please also visit http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2aac/44 . Need help!

Regards

Comment: what do you intend to do? your ' i intend to do is add all or any one or two IF conditions that are true.' is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select SUM(IF (faultdistribution='crs', 1,0)*8 +
    IF (faultdistribution='configuration', 1,0)* 6 +
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 4 +
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='major', 1,0)* 2 +
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='moderate', 1,0)* 5 +
    IF (faulttype='business' AND faultseverity='minor', 1,0)* 3 +
    IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='fatal', 1,0)* 2 +
    IF (faulttype='look & feel' AND faultseverity='major', 1,0)* 1) as mysum 
FROM tbl_fault 
WHERE product='DAS' 
AND faultdistribution='missed'
```